# Uninstall a languag package

Tags: magento2, uninstall

My magento is 2.2.2 and I found that I have **"ar_SA"** language package installed in my site!

To uninstall it, Can I run this command?

```
php bin/magento i18n:uninstall ar_SA
```

Comment: Please review : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-langpk.html#instgde-cli-uninst-lgpk-uninst

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall language package for that you need to perform in below format

```
:magento i18n:uninstall [-b|--backup-code] {language package name} ... {language package name}
```

For more detail please check documents link :
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-langpk.html

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean like this? php bin/magento i18n:uninstall [-b|--backup-code] {ar_SA}

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall language packages in magento 2 by using command line **i18n:uninstall**:

**Usage:**

```
php bin/magento i18n:uninstall [-b|–backup-code] package1 … [packageN]
```

**Arguments:**
package Language
package name

**Options:**

- –backup-code (-b) Take code and configuration files backup (excluding
  temporary files)
- –help (-h) Display this help message
- –quiet (-q) Do not output any message
- –verbose (-v|vv|vvv) Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal
  output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
- –version (-V) Display this application version
- –ansi Force ANSI output
- –no-ansi Disable ANSI output
- –no-interaction (-n) Do not ask any interactive question